# devise password in confirm email

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, devise, passwords

```
# in views/device/registration/new.html.erb:
<% password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8) %>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name, :locale => I18n.locale)) do |f| %>

 <%= f.hidden_field :password, :value => password %>
 <%= f.hidden_field :password_confirmation, :value => password %>

 <%= f.email_field :email %>

<%= f.submit "sign up" %>
<% end %>


# in views/device/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb:
<p>Your Password: <%# @ressource.password %></p>
```

i'm generating password for new user. user gets a confirmation email and this should be the correct place to put the generated password. (could be possible to send him the password after confirmation)

but in the email @resource.password is nil!

how to i send the given password in device confirmation email?
alternative could be to store pwd in db without encryption, but i didnt succeed on this as well.

Comment: Please do not make the mistake of storing passwords in your database in plain text. Leave this for the big corps. Also, you don't need to send passwords to your users when they register or try to recover their account. Check the `confirmable` Devise module. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/

Comment: i respect your opinion, and i would like to follow, but i dont want to anoy the user with 3 steps. i agreed to myself to use confirmation, but that should be all. there are some examples out to generate the password .... BUT how does the user login after confirmation? the only possibility is to reset_password, but than i could give the user also initially the password and confirmation inputs and this is a requirement (to autogenerate it). only solution to send the gernerated password in email! RIGHT?

Comment: Then I guess best way is to let the users pick their passwords initially. Also, whatever way you choose in the end, please avoid plain text passwords in db.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestions ... but my philisophy is that it should do whats required and not to force requirements what the it could handle. about saving password in db; i dont want ... thats why i use confirm email => in the process flow it must be still available, there must be a way to hand it over to mailer. after confirmation i guess it will be not possible - OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit hacky but workable solution to the problem you have mentioned.

```
# in views/device/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb:
<% pass = Devise.friendly_token.first(8) %>
<p>Your password is <%= pass %></p>
<% @resource.update_attributes( { :password => pass, :password_confirmation => pass }) %>
```

This way you set the password for your user and email them right away. You can keep the code in `views/device/registration/new.html.erb` unchanged as `user` creation will fail if you remove `password` and `password_confirmation` fields.

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with the solution proposed by Kulbir Saini, because updating the password in that way, makes some devise callback to change the token, making the the confirmation to fail.

To solve this, I have taken Kulbir's and modified some code to update the password, but avoiding any devise callback.

It isn't probably the best solution, but it does the trick.

```
<% pass = @resource.confirmation_token.first(8) %>
<p>Your password is: <%= pass %></p>
<% @resource.update_column(:encrypted_password, ::BCrypt::Password.create("#{pass}")) %>
```